# Ubuntu C++ Compiler Error: g++: error: file.cpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I am a C++ beginner and I am using an Ubuntu virtual machine on a Windows PC. Using Gedit, I made a simple file, called file.cpp, in a folder that I titled Projects in my Home directory. The file contains the C++ code for "Hello World". It appears that the C++ compiler can only compile the file when I enter in the terminal:

```
    g++ ~/Projects/file.cpp -o file
```

When I enter

```
    g++ file.cpp -o file
```

I get this error

```
    g++: error: file.cpp: No such file or directory
```

I don't want to unnecessarily have to type ~/Projects/ all the time when compiling .cpp files. How can I tell the compiler to always look in the Projects folder for .cpp files? I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: `cd ~/Projects` first.

Comment: Or write a Makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said by Daniel Kamil Kozar, you simply has to type `cd ~/Projects`. Or, open the terminal directly from the folder where your cpp's files are.

Answer (score 1):

Practically all linux shells invoke command line applications expecting that if a path is not provided then any files specified as arguments on the command line invoking the application will be in the current directory.

So `g++ file.cpp -o file` is the same as saying `g++ ./file.cpp -o ./file` where `./` means the current folder.

The change directory command, `cd` is used to set the current working directory. If you type `cd` it will change to your user's home directory. You can use the `cd` command and specify a relative path from the current directory, `cd ./Projects`, or an absolute path, `cd /home/rolf/Projects`. You can also use environment variables in the `cd` command as well such as `cd $HOME/Projects`.

To see what the current working directory is use the `pwd` command.